# Trying to Create Driver for Armature Layer

Tags: python, armature, drivers

```
import bpy
arm = bpy.data.armatures[bpy.context.active_object.name]  # type: ignore
drv = arm.driver_add('layers', 0)[0].driver
```

The error I receive here is: `TypeError: this type doesn't support IDProperties`

I'm working on an addon and isolated this part of the script as something I cannot figure out how to get working. This is run in EDIT_ARMATURE mode so the active object that is an armature is guaranteed.

I've also tried various other things like adding the driver to bpy.context.active_object, but then it complains that "layers" does not exist.

For context, I'm trying to create a driver that can toggle the visibility of an armature layer on or off based on a property. This can be done in Blender itself no problem, but I can't seem to get it working in Python.

Any guidance on properly adding a driver to the `layers` array of the armature is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. The bpy auto-complete module I was using type-annotated the result of `add_driver()` as a return type of `List[FCurve]` and was giving syntax errors without accessing the indexed result first with [0].

However it seems this must be an erroneous type annotation, as the [0] is not necessary, and I can access `.driver` directly on the return of the `add_driver()` function.

So my final line is `drv = arm.driver_add('layers', 0).driver`.